# Group a List by two criteria C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list

```
Class =>       Second      Third   Second  Fourth  Fifth  Second

Position =>     2           3       2       5        1     3
```

I want to create new list which has  Same class as well as same Positon

i.e new lists

```
Class  =>      Second       Second

Postion =>       2             2


Class  =>         Second

Position =>         3


Class  =>          Third

Position =>          3
```

and so on

can i use muliple GroupBy on parent list to produce these different list or first i  should 
GroupBy "Class"  and then by "Position" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group by `position` and `class` at once. One `GroupBy()`.

For instance:

```
var groupedByTwoThingsAtOnce = myList
   .GroupBy(i => new { Class = i.Class, Position = i.Position });
```

Answer (score 6):

... and as to *how* you group by two things at once:

```
var groupedByTwoThingsAtOnce = myList
    .GroupBy(i => new { Class = i.Class, Position = i.Position });
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use an anonymous type for the grouping and then GroupBy any number of properties.
Could be something like the following

```
.GroupBy(item => new {ClassGroup = item.Class, PositionGroup = item.Position})
```

If you can use the anonymous type (for example, if you need to return the grouped result out of the current method), you could also try using a Tuple

```
.GroupBy(item => new Tuple<string, int>(item.Class, item.Position))
```